# Is there a way to get the attempt number of a spark job running on yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I was wondering if there is a way to programmatically get the attempt number of a spark job running on yarn.

I already tried using `SparkListenerApplicationStart` with this listener and regisetring it when launching a spark-submit

```scala
class Listner extends SparkListener{
  var att = ""
  override def onApplicationStart(applicationStart: SparkListenerApplicationStart): Unit = {
    att = applicationStart.appAttemptId.getOrElse("")
    println(s"--------------------------------------$att------------------------------------------------")
  }
```

however `att` is always empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my question:

```scala
    val yc = YarnClient.createYarnClient()
    yc.init(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
    yc.start()
    val id = ApplicationId.fromString(spark.sparkContext.applicationId)
    val attempts = yc.getApplicationAttempts(id)
```